# ios. Validate if Analytics datas in stand by

Tags: objective-c, ios5, google-analytics

I'm using the google analytics sdk to send data.

I'm looking for a way to know if, sor some reason,  the analytics data are waiting on the ipad database(offline, etc)

Is there a flag ou method to validate this(data waiting)?

Thanks